# OpenShift trying to connect with mySql

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, openshift

I am trying connect to external mySql database. 
I get this error message on console:

`Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'adminbnnSIES'@'localhost' (using password: YES))`

`Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection`

This is how my applicationContext.xml looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gwozdz.spring.service"></context:component-scan>
    <!-- Create Data Source bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.X.XX.X:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="adminbnnSIES" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Define SessionFactory bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>domain-classes.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

I couldnt find answer for my answer anywhere. 
In my pom.xml i have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.31</version>
</dependency>
```

On local connection I dont have such problem, here is my local bean setup:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem should be with the host you are specifying there, "localhost" doesn't seem right for an external database.

This Openshift guide might be helpful:

https://blog.openshift.com/cloud-connections-how-to-use-openshift-with-external-databases/

The code they used in the guide is here:

https://github.com/codemiller/hellodb-java